# How to set application's taskbar icon in Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, pyqt

How do I set an application's taskbar icon in PyQt4?

I have tried setWindowIcon, and it successfully sets the icon in the top-left of the main window, but it does not affect the icon shown in the Windows 7 taskbar -- the taskbar icon remains the default Python pyw icon. Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mainwindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mainwindow.show()

app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('chalk.ico'))
mainwindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('chalk.ico'))
app.exec_()
```

[update] I've tried placing the `setWindowIcon()` before the `show()`. I've tried it with other images, ico and png. Nothing helps.

Comment: Does setting the icon before you `.show()` the window help?

Comment: No, it makes no difference if I set the icon before `.show()`.

Comment: Did you try another image file? Your code works fine for me with a random png file, though I'm using KDE4.

Comment: Btw - does the problem reproduce on Win XP or Vista? If not, consult http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/support/help - but please share your findings here :)

Comment: I tried other image files, and it still doesn't work. I don't have WinXP or Vista available to test this on. If someone tests the code on these systems, please let us know the answer. I've posted a query to the PyQt mailing list.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I've found the answer, after some digging.

In Windows 7, the taskbar is not for "Application Windows" per se, it's for "Application User Models". For example, if you have several different instances of your application running, and each instance has its own icon, then they will all be grouped under a single taskbar icon. Windows uses various heuristics to decide whether different instances should be grouped or not, and in this case it decided that everything hosted by Pythonw.exe should be grouped under the icon for Pythonw.exe.

The correct solution is for Pythonw.exe to tell Windows that it is merely hosting other applications. Perhaps a future release of Python will do this. Alternatively, you can add a registry key to tell Windows that Pythonw.exe is just a host rather than an application in its own right. See MSDN documentation for [AppUserModelIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459%28VS.85%29.aspx#host).

Alternatively, you can use a Windows call from Python, to explicitly tell Windows what the correct AppUserModelID is for this process:

```py
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

EDIT: Please see [Ronan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872625): the myappid string should be unicode.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it fixes your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks! I needed the same thing using PySide.

Comment: How to find out what is myappid ?

Comment: @aBiologist it's arbitrary string

Comment: Works well also with tkinter

Comment: This also works with Windows 10, for anyone wondering. I'm not sure if this works with Windows 8 or 8.1 though.

Comment: Works like charm on Windows 10. Plus great explanation. Too bad I can only upvote this once.

Comment: Well it seems to work for everyone else but not for me with wxPython on Windows 10 too. Where exactly do you guys put it in your code? And how do you launch your Python script?

Comment: Thank you; this solved also for me (python 3.11, tkinter); I just added `if sys.platform == 'win32':` to avoid using it on linux. @Nicryc I put the lines DamonJW wrote (without worrying for unicode since on python3) in the main python file, before doing anything (even before the `Tk()` call), and I call the script either in a batch script (`python.exe main.py`) or through a shortcut to avoid console (`pythonw.exe main.py`)

Answer (score 19):

[@DamonJW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552105) will work, but there is a minor catch: myappid should be unicode (argument type is PCWSTR).

```py
import ctypes
myappid = u'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

Otherwise getting the AppUserModelID will get wrong unicode characters (`祭潣灭湡⹹祭牰摯捵⹴畳灢潲畤瑣瘮牥楳湯`):

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
lpBuffer = wintypes.LPWSTR()
AppUserModelID = ctypes.windll.shell32.GetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID
AppUserModelID(ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(lpBuffer), wintypes.LPWSTR))
appid = lpBuffer.value
ctypes.windll.kernel32.LocalFree(lpBuffer)
if appid is not None:
    print(appid)
```

That said, it is a minor thing, since Windows will still recognize the unicode string as "another process" and switch the icon accordingly.

Comment: I could not get your code to work, but the answer from @DamonJW worked for me.

Comment: The first part of my code is the same as @DamonJW's, except for the `u` prepended in the `myappid` string. The second part is just the check for the actual string that Windows is "seeing".

Comment: Nice addition. Presumably this is a non-issue on Python 3 as all strings are unicode.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will break on a non-windows machine e.g. Linux, if so you can wrap that with a check of `os.name` https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.name#os.name

Answer (score 10):

You must set the AppUserModelID before your app shows any GUI. If you need to access other Windows 7 features you can have a look at [Q7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/q7goodies/) which is a Qt add-on for Windows 7 with a PyQt bindings.

Comment: that's an important detail that should be in the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Working example using PyQt6 and Windows 11. This code will change the taskbar icon from the Python interpreter icon to what you set using **self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('gui/icons/Logo.png'))**

```py
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID('company.app.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 the solution looks slightly different:

```py
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' 
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
time.sleep(1)
```

Whit out the delay an icon just blinking and disappeared.
With the delay it is woks OK.