# Loading an image using QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have an image file , as `C:/44637landscapes-2007.jpg`

I want to load this file using `QPixmap` using PySide

I tried as following .

```
pixmap = QPixmap('C:/44637landscapes-2007.jpg')
```

But documentation says like `QPixmap(':/xxxxxx.jpeg')` . What does `':'` means ?

How do I load an image at `'C:\'` ?

EDIT : The problem was with trying to load `"JPEG"` . It was able to load `"PNG"` , with no issues. So what else , I need to do to load `"JPEG"` ?

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to build your Python code to an executable this covers the issue for .ico files but the process is the same for JPEG:
[PyQt/PySide - icon display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573995/pyqt-pyside-icon-display-problem/5643540#5643540)

If you're having problems when running from your installed interpreter then your path variable probably isn't set correctly, your qt.conf (in the base python dir) has been deleted/changed or you don't have qjpeg4.dll where its supposed to be (`<python dir>\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\imageformats`).

My qt.conf looks like:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/PySide
Binaries = .
Plugins = plugins
Translation = translation
```

`C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/PySide` is part of my system PATH variable and **ahead** of any PyQt (or other Qt) directories.

Comment: No problem, out of curiosity what was the actual problem? I took a bit of a shotgun approach there in the list of possible solutions.

Comment: Problem was qt.conf path was not correct. It was pointing to wrong plugin folder .

Answer (score 5):

Qt does something a little weird with images. If you are using only pngs you will never have a problem.  The handling of other image formats is handled a little differently.

If you take a look in your Qt directory (where all the binaries and source is) you will find a directory called:  `plugins\imageformats`

In that directory there are a ton of `dlls` (or `.so`) one for each image format that Qt supports.  In your case I presume the one that interests you is `qjpeg4.dll`

Now, when you run your application and you try to use a `jpeg`, Qt will try to load this plugin, but if it can't find it, then your image won't show up.

We had a similar problem with ico files.  It worked in our development environment because the Qt folder was in our `PATH,` and therefore it magically found this plugin.  However, when we were releasing our software we would distribute only those dlls that we needed, and therefore it didn't work.

After much investigation this is what we did:

- Our application is located in a bin/ directory.  This is where the exe, and all Qt dlls are put.  `QtCore4.dll` and `QtGui4.dll` etc...
- Under the bin directory we create a subdirectory called `'imageformats'`
- Put `qjpeg4.dll` and any other image plugins you might need.
- Change the code as follows:

  `QApplication _App(argc, argv);`

  `// Find the path of your bin directory - whereever your exe resides.`

  `QString _Path = _PathToBin + QString(QDir::separator()) + "imageformats");`

  `// This line is providing a path to Qt telling it to look here for plugins`
  `QApplication::addLibraryPath(_Path);`

  `// Initialize the main form`

  `return _App.exec();`

  This should make sure that Qt is aware of the `jpeg` handling plugin, and load your image in the `UI`.

Answer (score 4):

You can construct an instance of QPixMap by providing the path name of the file. What is the error you get when you try your code ? Change your code to something like:

```
pixmap = QPixMap(r'C:\filename.jpeg')
```

The documentation what you are referring to is the way you would load a Qt resource. One can convert an image that is needed by the application to a Qt resource so as to load it in a platform independent manner. For steps to do so refer to [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/resources.html)
 documentation.

Comment: I am not getting any error. When ,I tried like pixmap = QPixmap() pixmap.load('r^C:\abc.jpeg') . It's returning 'false' . That means loading didn't work .

Comment: If you are able to load the pixmap then what is the issue ?

Comment: I am not able to load the image. According to the documentation if it returns "false" , I think it doesn't load the image . '

Comment: When you create an instance of pixmap the image also gets loaded (provided the file exists and the format is readable) else you get a null object.

Comment: When I tried loading a PNG it worked. I think for loading JPEG , something extra needs to be done .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Pixmap=setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("path_image"))
```

Comment: Rather than dumping non-sentences like "try this", read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: In addition to above, using phrases like "Thanks" and "Try this ..." risks getting the post misunderstood and perceived as something other than an answer. "Thanks" seems to refer to a solution somebody else provided. "Try this ..." seems like a proposed experiment, something to find out more and which might result in an answer via new insights - but in itself is indeed not an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).