# Pygame program looking different when debuging from visual studio code versus running from command prompt

Tags: python, cmd, pygame

I am making chess in python using pygame. The starting menu is composed of two buttons. Their border is renderd to the screen using

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), text1rect.inflate(20, 20), 10)
```

This is the code that I use to do this:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Chess")

icon = pygame.image.load("./Images/wking.png").convert_alpha()
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

font = pygame.font.Font("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 32)
text1 = font.render("Create game", True, (0, 255, 0), (124, 124, 124))
text1_rect = text1.get_rect(center = (400, 300))

text2 = font.render("Join game", True, (0, 255, 0), (124, 124, 124))
text2_rect = text2.get_rect(center = (400, 500))


board = pygame.image.load("./Images/board.png").convert()

def main():
    scene_to_render = "menu"
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        is_clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        if scene_to_render == "menu":
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(text1, text1_rect)
            screen.blit(text2, text2_rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), text1_rect.inflate(20, 20), 10)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), text2_rect.inflate(20, 20), 10)

            if text1_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and is_clicked:
                pass
            if text2_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos) and is_clicked:
                pass

        # Obviously there is more code but that is not important because only the menu buttons are broken when starting from the command prompt

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(16)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The window and taskbar icon also dosen't appear when starting from the command prompt, being replaced with the standard python application icon. I understand this can be fixed when compiling to .exe with pyinstaller using a command.

The user Zack explains this in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10438300/18072034

> With pyinstaller for example, you would call python pyinstaller.py --icon=icon.ico

This is how the menu looks when starting from vscode:

[image: How the menu looks when debuging in vscode]

This is how the menu looks when running from cmd:

[image: How the menu looks when running from cmd]

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out while writting the question, the problem was fixed after upgrading pip and pygame to the latest versions by entering in the command prompt the following commands: (Make sure you open command prompt as an administartor when doing this)

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade pygame
```

Also, because I fixed the problem before finishing the question I couldn't make a screenshot of a problem. The image that showcases the broken menu is edited but also very simmilar to how it actualy looked.