# Where is this warning being raised 'QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.'?

Tags: python, qt, compiler-warnings

My code is throwing the warning (not sure if this is actually a warning)

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
```

but nothing else. It does not tell me which part of the code is raising it.

How can I know which part of my code is triggering this warning?

Comment: Sorry, mind reading machine is broken again. Can you post your code? :)

Comment: That's the whole point, I don't know where in my code this warning happens since no clue is given by the warning itself. The code is thousands of lines long.

Comment: Did you enable fusion style? Can you show the code before the initialization of QApplication?

Comment: No idea what *fusion style* is and I do not initialize QApplication anywhere in my code that I am aware of (I don't even know what that means/does) I'll use some `print` statements to try and pin down the issue.

Comment: Don't you have anywhere in your code a line like "app = QApplication(sys.argv)" ??

Comment: I don't even have the word *QApplication* in my code.

Comment: Well if you don't use Qt at all in your code then either you use some libraries that use Qt, or you launch from your code an application based on Qt, or the message you see in console is not generated by your application at all... Can't be more specific without knowing which OS you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt5 does now show icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080247/pyqt5-does-now-show-icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know which part of my code is triggering this warning?

Start with the parts of your code that invoke a GUI. Given that the OP appears to be a scientist, I'll take a wild guess that `matplotlib` is involved. I can reproduce the message with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2])
```

using the following package versions (from `conda list`):

```
matplotlib                2.2.2            py36h0e671d2_1    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h751905a_0    defaults
qt                        5.9.4                h4e5bff0_0    defaults
```

Comment: I have those exact versions except that `matplotlib` and `pyqt` are the `27` versions (since I am working with Python 2.7)

Comment: @Gabriel can you reproduce the message with the 2-line example I gave?  If so, please consider marking this question as solved.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a Matplotlib issue (see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11775). It might be an Anaconda issue.

Comment: @Alejandro It's definitely not an Anaconda issue. I got the warning and I do not even have anaconda installed. It's a QT issue it seems. ;)

Answer (score 9):

The cause for this message is that the environment variable *QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE* is set on your system to a value not supported by your Qt installation. You can check this with

```
    sh-prompt> set | grep QT
```

To fix this warning, you can either change the variable in `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`, or -if only one program is affected- start the program with

```
    QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" program
```

Unsetting the varible with `qputenv` in your program code (as *Harvey* suggested)  will have the side effect that style preferences are ignored by your application even on systems that support it.

Answer (score 4):

This problem comes from qt 5.9.2 and pyqt 5.9.2. 
This problem is known to Anaconda team and they are ignoring it because it primarily comes from qt.

I got this error for anaconda-navigator (Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64) and this caused my Spyder (v3.2.8) IDE for Python 3.6 getting invisible. Downgrading qt and pyqt solved the problem.

To downgrade, type in console:

```
conda install pyqt=5.6
```

Note: In case, your conda is not updated, you need to update conda before running the above command. To update conda run:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

Hope this will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]: I just found a better solution for my own C++ code. It is still only a "workaround," but the warning is gone. Add one line at the very top of the `main()` function, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE",0);
    ...
```

This will unset the environment variable causing the warning.

[OLD ANSWER]:

```
Error message:
 QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.

To remove this error message:
 In Qt Creator (ver 4.4.1)
  Select "Projects" (wrench icon on left edge)
   Under "Build & Run" (left pane)
    Select "Run"
     Under "Run Settings" (right pane)
      Under "Run Environment"
       Select "Details" (drop down list)
        Scroll down to "QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE"
         Click it to highlight it
         Then click "Unset" button (right side)
       Click "Details" to close the list

Now when you run the application you shouldn't see this error message.
```

Comment: I am not using Qt Creator.

Comment: I just today found a much better workaround. Qt Creator not involved now. Edited my answer.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Is it C++ code?

Comment: @Gabriel yes it is C++ code. (Ignore the "OLD ANSWER.") I am using Qt, but I expect this may work for anyone with any Qt code somewhere in their project. If you are getting this error, then you quite certainly have Qt code somewhere since it is a complaint from "QApplication: ..." The main() function is the standard starting point for any C++ application. Are you using C++?

Comment: @Gabriel I see you have the Python tag. Hopefully you can find an equivalent statement to put at the very beginning of your Python code, to set this environment variable QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE to an empty string "" (or NULL, as I did.)

Comment: The OLD ANSWER did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I installed anaconda.

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```

---

```
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
```

When running spyder from anaconda-navigator:

```
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder.sh: line 3: 31873 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) spyder >
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-out-1.txt 2>
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-err-1.txt
```

When running spyder from the command line:

```
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder.sh: line 3: 31873 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) spyder > 
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-out-1.txt 2> 
/home/username/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder-err-1.txt
```

This fixed my problem:

```
$ conda install pyqt=5.6
```

Many thanks to Narnia_Optimus