# Is there any option in tkinter to change the taskbar Icon?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new in tkinter. I am trying to change the icon of the Tkinter window but it's change only the icon of the top title bar in the window, But I'm also want to change the icon which is present in the taskbar. Is there any way to solve it?

```
root.wm_iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Jawad Saqib\Desktop\Desktop\Python\jawad.ico')
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900510/changing-the-application-and-taskbar-icon-python-tkinter

Answer (score 1):

To change the icon displayed in the actual window, (assuming root is the `Tk()` instance, you run `root.iconbitmap(icon)`.

To change the icon displayed in the taskbar, you'd need to compile to code into exe or your system executable and set an icon, because the icon in the taskbar is the exe that's running. In this case, the executable that is running is python, and it is displaying the python icon. Or the tkinter icon - it varies on platform.

Eg. `pyinstaller --icon=icon.ico myscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

No,

you can like make it to an [exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons) and then also give it an taskbar icon but, because the python is executed in a python launcher it wil not can changed trough code.