# Python EasyGUI Changing Taskbar Icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, easygui

I've been using easyGUI to build a GUI for my python script. I'm having trouble finding a way to change the taskbar icon.

I am also using pyinstaller to convert the python file to a exe and was able to change the exe's icon, but when I run the file the easyGUI blue feather appears in the taskbar. I've seen how you can change it in Tkinter, I know that easyGUI uses Tkinter, but how can I miniplate the taskbar icon while using easyGUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Icon customization is not supported currently with easyGUI**. However, you can add support for this relatively easily.

---

Let's take a look at a random easyGUI object: `ChoiceBox`. The source code for this very simple. (Find it in your `Lib\site-packages\easygui\boxes` folder.) You can follow the same routine for any type of easyGUI window you're using. A bit lengthy, but it works.

```
def choicebox(msg="Pick an item", title="", choices=None, preselect=0,
              callback=None,
              run=True):
    """
    The ``choicebox()`` provides a list of choices in a list box to choose
    from. The choices are specified in a sequence (a tuple or a list).

    :param str msg: the msg to be displayed
    :param str title: the window title
    :param list choices: a list or tuple of the choices to be displayed
    :param preselect: Which item, if any are preselected when dialog appears
    :return: A string of the selected choice or None if cancelled
    """

    mb = ChoiceBox(msg, title, choices, preselect=preselect,
                   multiple_select=False,
                   callback=callback)

    if run:
        reply = mb.run()
        return reply
    else:
        return mb
```

Let's add a new parameter to this, called icon.

```
def choicebox(msg="Pick an item", title="", choices=None, preselect=0,
              callback=None,
              run=True, icon=None):
```

We need to add it to the underlying class as well, `ChoiceBox`.

```
mb = ChoiceBox(msg, title, choices, preselect=preselect,
                   multiple_select=False,
                   callback=callback, icon=icon)
```

Next, in the ChoiceBox class, we do the same thing. Note how I added `icon` to the `GUItk` object's parameters.

```
class ChoiceBox(object):

    def __init__(self, msg, title, choices, preselect, multiple_select, callback, icon):

        ...

        self.ui = GUItk(msg, title, self.choices, preselect_list, multiple_select,
                        self.callback_ui, icon)
```

Here's the `GUItk __init__` code. Add the `icon` parameter to this as well. We'll also finally call the actual method that will do the changing of icons for us.

```
def __init__(self, msg, title, choices, preselect, multiple_select, callback, icon):

        ...

        self.config_root(title) #No need to add this line, just for location reference.
        self.config_icon(icon) #Add this line
```

And finally, the `config_icon` method, which you should also put right below the `config_root` method.

```
def config_icon(self, icon):
        if icon:
            self.boxRoot.iconbitmap(icon)
```

Add it to your code like this: `choicebox(choices=['choice1', 'choice2'], icon="pathto\icon.ico")`

And then if you compile this version of easyGUI into your pyinstaller, it should appear. (Remember the value of icon should be a string of a path pointing to an `.ico` file. Also, note this has no error handling built in. If the path to your icon is wrong, then it won't catch that.) If you're trying to run it without pyinstaller, view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34547834/9731347).

**Hope this was helpful!** I know it's tedious, but it stays relatively consistent with the rest of the module.

Comment: This answer worked! thank you, I am now applying this to the remaining easygui objects