# how to add an taskbar icon for my application

Tags: python, wxpython

I use wxpython on windows7 to write a small app. I hope to add an icon for  app in the taskbar. My code is :

```
self.icon = wx.Icon("taskbaricon.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
self.SetIcon(self.icon)
```

It works well in the alt-tab.

But in the taskbar of windows, it just show the defualt python icon:

So how to change the windows taskbar icon?
Thank you for your help and a small  program demo can be the best!

Answer (score 1):

This has been raised before, and I think the answers here can will solve your problem
[wxpython icon for task bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223952/wxpython-icon-for-task-bar)

It's not technically possible on Windows but the answers here list a few ways to get it to work, mostly through py2exe.

Comment: I have seen the links you give before I ask my question. I do not want to make my app to an exe. So may be there is no way to solve the icon problem

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is first to develop the whole application, then compile the application using [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).
First open the command prompt and change the working directory to the one your application is located and then execute the following command,
    pyinstaller --windowed --icon="icon.ico" your_main_script.py
assuming the icon you want to use is called icon.ico.
I find pyinstaller easier to use than py2exe and is available for the 2.x and 3.x versions of pyhton.