# Main Window icon missing using Pyside6

Tags: python, pyside6

I'm probably missing something obvious, but the following code doesn't seem to display the app_icon in the window title bar. The app_icon.png is a 24x24px file in the same folder as main.py and ui_mainwindow.py. The [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QIcon.html) seems to suggest *PySide6.QtGui.QIcon(fileName)* is a valid approach, but maybe I'm misinterpreting it. Aside from this issue, the rest of the app works fine.

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QScreen
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QMainWindow
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Change a few things
        screenSize = QScreen.availableGeometry(QApplication.primaryScreen())
        winXpos = ((screenSize.width() - self.width())/2)
        winYpos = ((screenSize.height() - self.height())/2)
        self.move(winXpos, winYpos)
        self.setWindowTitle('App - Main Window')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('app_icon.png'))
        ...rest of the code...
```

Changing it to the following, results in an error

```
self.setWindowIcon(QIcon.addFile('app_icon.png'))
TypeError: descriptor 'addFile' for 'PySide6.QtGui.QIcon' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

This is on linux, using Python3.8.10 and PySide6. The form was put together with Qt Creator and the .ui converted to .py using pyside6-uic. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:
[screenshot of missing icon, post changes suggested in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3rJM.png)

Comment: `addFile` is not a static function, and it also returns `None`, so you need an instance of QIcon (`icon = QIcon()`), then use `icon.addFile('app_icon.png')`, and finally `setWindowIcon(icon)`, but that's probably not the problem here. Are you sure that the icon is in the same path from which you're running the script? Try with a simple `print(QPixmap('app_icon.png').isNull())`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is since `addFile` is not a static function, calling it directly from the `QIcon` class will not work. Instead, I think you need to instantiate a `QIcon` object and apply `addFile` to it:

```py
my_icon = QIcon()
my_icon.addFile('app_icon.png')

self.setWindowIcon(my_icon)
```

As a suggestion, test if the file exists (`os.path.isfile`) and that on Linux you have read access to it. Alternatively, try creating a `QPixmap` from the file path and test to see if the pixmap is null (`None` in Python)

(as @musicamante suggests, it could be it cannot find your file for one reason or another).

Additionally, try

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

my_pixmap = QPixmap(":/app_icon.png")
my_icon = QIcon(my_pixmap)

self.setWindowIcon(my_icon)
```

see [the Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qrcfiles.html) for details.

Comment: That wouldn't work, as `addFile()` returns `None`. An instance must be created, then `addFile()` will be called on that instance, and finally `setWindowIcon()` will be used. But that shouldn't change much from the file name constructor, so, that's not the problem here.

Comment: @musicamante I think we're both hitting on the same thing, just at slightly different times (like ships crossing in the night).

Comment: They're all in the same folder, **os.path.isfile** returns **True** for each of the files. The above approach works, sort of - the icon is now visible on the panel/taskbar, but not of the app window itself.

Comment: @CodgerCoder Do you have `qrc` file for your icons? If so, make sure `app_icon.png` is in the same directory as the `qrc` file, or in one of its subdirectories. Second, try `my_icon.addFile(":/app_icon.png")`.

Comment: @A.Hendry `setIconSize()` is for the default icon size of the tool bars, it has nothing to do with the window icon (for which the size is decided by the system)

Comment: @CodgerCoder do you mean that the icon is shown in the taskbar, but not in the top left corner of the window? And if you cycle windows via alt-tab, does it show?

Comment: @musicamante Fair point.

Comment: @CodgerCoder Have you tried serializing your icon and importing it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068003/application-icon-in-pyside-gui

Comment: Thanks for the help. musicmante -  Yes, it shows in the taskbar, but not the top left corner of the window. Alt-tabbing doesn't change that behaviour but the icon also shows up on the list of windows you can tab through. A.Hendry - I see the same thing if I make the _.qrc_ and then convert it to a _.py_ using **pyside6-rrc** as per the [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qrcfiles.html), although there looks to be an errant _</ui>_ in their example. Will look at the thread you suggest.

Comment: Serialising the icon doesn't seem to make any difference either. Added a screenshot to the original post which hopefully illustrates the issue.