# Windows taskbar (Windows 7?) -- how to set the application name in the Control Panel notifications dialog

Tags: python, windows, pyside, system-tray

The Windows 7 Control Panel "Notification Area Icons" allows you to customize which system tray icons are visible. For each of the icons, it shows two things:

- an application name
- a subtitle

It looks like the subtitle comes from the tooltip text, because I can set that.

**But what about the application name?** I'm writing a GUI in PySide and can't figure out what incantations I need to do, to set this to something other than "python.exe".

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's the same issue, but could [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1552105/984421) be relevant?

Answer (score 3):

`python.exe` will always show up if the module is run under the python executable, regardless of via a shortcut or not. It also shows up in task manager under the process name `python.exe`.

To circumvent this, it is necessary to create a custom executable to run the python script under it's own name. This doesn't have to be a monolithic exe packer such as py2exe, but can be something a little more discrete.

Using effbot.org's open source [ExeMaker](http://effbot.org/zone/exemaker.htm) for instance, the following steps will result in what you want.

After [downloading](http://effbot.org/downloads#exemaker) exemaker, simply run it from the command line with

```
exemaker scriptname.py
```

and it'll create `scriptname.exe`.

You may then run `scriptname.exe` by double clicking it, and it shall run the python script under it's own name.

The advantage of this small tool is that any changes made to the python script **do not** require recompilation of the exe - they are effective immediately.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are launching your application using *Python.exe*. In your case the main application running is *Python.exe*, so the *Notification Area Icons* will always show you *Python.exe* as running application.

When you are done with the development of your application, use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to package your application. After this process you will have a *exe* file for your application, when you will run your application, the name in the *Notification Area Icons* for your application will be same as you will set for your main window title.

Comment: so you have to have an EXE file to provide this information? bummer.

Answer (score -2):

I did not really test it but it may work. Create a link to your .py file and choose the name. If you run that link it should show the name of the link.
PS: On command prompt title bar it works fine

Comment: That won't do it I'm afraid; it's still shown as python.exe. If you make a copy of python.exe and rename it to MyProgram.exe then that will show up as the program title, but that's a pretty ugly solution.

Comment: Ok. I do not have any other solutions. Sorry

Comment: Should you really be adding this as an answer if you do not know if it works ?  With all due respect, it just becomes a distraction when reading.

Comment: I tested it at windows XP but i do not know if it works on windows 7. But maybe this is his only chance to do that. If it was so he/she could be happy that it works.