# How to hide taskbar icon of a PyQt4 Python application?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I want to create a windows desktop widget. I will create a custom UI for the widget in Qt Designer and add functionality using Python. But, I do not want the application to have an icon on the taskbar at all. How should I modify my code and make my application (and its instances or other similar applications) to have no task bar footprint?

How can I hide the taskbar icon on windows? Here is an example code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('try.ui')

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is its ui, "try.ui":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>211</width>
    <height>157</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>60</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCL0V.png) is how default icon looks like on the taskbar. I just do not want it there, as expected from a widget.

Comment: How does the icon look? What does it say? Is it the default pythonwindows icon?

Comment: @MiteshNinja: It's just a regular default icon showing on the taskbar, but I do not want it there and could not find a way to hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
...
class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)       #This
```

Comment: Thank you Stevo, this is it. I want to note something funny about this method though: When I run a second instance, for the first time, the original instance disappears, if I run couple of more instances and click on desktop, they all disappear from screen. After that however on secondary trials, all works fine. I do not know what causes this at this point but your answer solves my problem and I accepted it. Do you also know how to make the app frame-less at the same time? This would be more like a widget.

Comment: I think that's a whole new question, but quick answer would be to use the same method: `setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105) may be the problem:

> In Windows 7, the taskbar is not for "Application Windows" per se,
>   it's for "Application User Models". For example, if you have several
>   different instances of your application running, and each instance has
>   its own icon, then they will all be grouped under a single taskbar
>   icon. Windows uses various heuristics to decide whether different
>   instances should be grouped or not, and in this case it decided that
>   everything hosted by Pythonw.exe should be grouped under the icon for
>   Pythonw.exe.
>
> The correct solution is for Pythonw.exe to tell Windows that it is
>   merely hosting other applications. Perhaps a future release of Python
>   will do this. Alternatively, you can add a registry key to tell
>   Windows that Pythonw.exe is just a host rather than an application in
>   its own right. See MSDN documentation for AppUserModelIDs.
>
> Alternatively, you can use a Windows call from Python, to explicitly
>   tell Windows what the correct AppUserModelID is for this process:

```
import ctypes myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' #
arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I do not want the application to have an icon on the taskbar at all. How should I modify my code and make my application (and its instances or other similar applications) to have no task bar footprint? This is more like what I need. Thank you for the reply.