# WxPython icon in the taskbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, icons, wxpython, taskbar

I use wxpython and I try to add an icon to my application. However, The icon isn't shown in the taskbar only at the left side of the application. I use wxpython 4.0.7 . I used before another version of wxpython and it worked. some one knows why it doesn't work? This is my code:

```
import wx
ICON = "icon_path"

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500))
frame.SetIcon(wx.Icon(ICON, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))
frame.Show(True)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If your icon is not showing... What icon appears in the taskbar? ¿The generic python app icon? Please paste the entire code and if possible any screenshot of the taskbar.

Are you using W7... Have you tried this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105?

Comment: In the left top of the app the icon appears and in the taskbar it shows white sign similar to a file in his shape. As I said, in a specific version that I had before, the icon was shown. I don't remember which version was it.

Comment: There is no reason why the icon is seen in one place but not in the other (unless it is a Windows configuration). If you put an example of the code we could see what is happening.

Comment: I added the code but, as I told this code showed the icon in both places in other version of wx-python. currently I work with wxpython-4.0.7 . I tried to downgrade the version to 4.0.6 and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works fine with 4.0.7.post1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5. Is the version that I am using on Windows 7.