# Setting the Same Icon as Application Icon in Task bar for pyqt5 application

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am finding trouble with attaching the same icon in the task bar manager for pyqt5 application as I did for the icon of pyqt5 application. I have attached below code for icon display in pyqt5, just need a bit help that how to code for displaying of same icon of Application to the task bar.
[image]

[image]

```
import sys
from SplashScreen import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, qGray, QImage, QPainter, QPalette,QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('./cricket.png'))
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(300,300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Quick Cricket')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image. Then, ensure that you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `import sys
from SplashScreen import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, qGray, QImage, QPainter, QPalette,QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('./cricket.png'))
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(300,300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Quick Cricket')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: Here is the sample code

Comment: don't use comments, as they don't support formatting and they make difficult to read code. Edit the question instead, and follow the guidelines about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: @musicamante still waiting for answer

Comment: I just pointed out problems in your questions, it doesn't mean I know tje answer. Please avoid unnecessary usage of comments, and *be patient*, this is not a forum nor a chat, and absolutely not a race: sometimes answers are given *years` after a question is asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess What I found the Answer.

I used three lines of Code at the start of my application and then run the code and windows show me same icon as it was my logo.

```
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

What these lines do? So in short these lines will tell the window that this is my own registered application, so I will decide the icon of it.

I will give all credit to  @DamonJW Stack Overflow Developer. Thanks @DamonJW.
Here is the link of solution

<
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551605/how-to-set-applications-taskbar-icon-in-windows-7/1552105#1552105%3E)

Comment: Please post links as *actual* links, and read the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The solution is in this line

```
import ctypes
myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version' # arbitrary string
ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.